# wordpress site requesting to wrong url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, http-status-code-404, config

This website was in one server, and that server failed, so an automatic backup has made. the problem is that now it looks like a lot of files are missing, if I check the console in the browser there is a lot of 404 errors, and the requested URL is wrong.

Is there a kind of configuration file in which I can set the url that wordpress should use to request the files?

Update:
Only the .js, .css and .png files are wrong requested, the .php and .html files are fine.

Comment: It may be an issue with the trailing slash into the home URL and site URL.
The URL should be "http://example.com/". Add the slash in the last of the website URL.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask similar questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the file I was searching for is wp-config.php, and the line that did the trick is

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
```

I don't know what was the problem, but I basically solved it overwriting that config variable.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the trailing slash into the home URL and site URL. The URL should be "example.com". Add the slash in the last of the website URL.

Try with adding a trailing slash in the site URL and home URL.